# Disappearing elements and strange behaviour when switching from html to php

Tags: php, html, css, adobe-brackets

EDIT! -- **The problem was to do with the browser Cache and the solution is to do a hard refresh in Chrome (CTRL + F5)**

My site seems to break when switching over to from .html to .php and is not acting as expected when adding simple div elements with classes and using spanned styles or h tags.

Essentially I'm trying to add 2 simple elements to my page.

```
• A heading consisting of boldened and centered text. 

• A div that will act as a vertical timeline.
```

Once I have added these elements using a h1 tag with custom styles and a simple div assigned to a class, it works as expected..

Until I add more text underneath my heading, at which point it breaks; my custom h1 tag style applied to my heading is no longer active and my timeline div disappears from view!

Even stranger.. when I delete the text the problem is still there. Even after I delete the timeline div the problem still persists.

Its only after I actually go into the css and delete the .timeline class does the span actually come back into effect, which to me makes no sense at all!

The problem is not present before switching over to php so this is how I switched from working in html to php code:

1. Open xampp Control Panel and ran 'Apache' and 'MySQL' and open my website project in Adobe Brackets.
2. Change the file extension of my index file from .html to .php .
3. Change the 'Live Preview Base URL to point to my project's directory in xampp's htdocs folder.

At this point the live preview works okay (apart from having to save to see updates)

4. Insert my heading into my document inside h1 tag and apply styles to h1 tag in css document
5. Create a div with a class to act as my timeline bar

At this stage, it will break if I add a line of text to the document ("is this working!?")

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 46px;">

     <h1> BIOGRAPHY </h1>

     Is this working!?

     <div class="timeline"></div>


</div>
```

```css
h1 {
    font-weight: 650;
    text-align: center;  
}

.timeline {
    width: 10px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: #454545;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Sorry for the very long question and I hope it makes sense. I'm probably making a really silly mistake but I'm struggling to see what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: This issue is almost certainly related to things not being received by the browser, because the server isn't sending them. Check your web console in Chrome; did everything come down correctly? Specifically, stylesheets, js files, and images are likely missing. As you might know, the client doesn't care about server-side rendering; it's just receiving data from _somewhere_.  Your server-side web server error log may also help.

Comment: This looks more like a browser issue to me.
Are you using bootstrap?
Because I noticed a `class="row"` in one of your `<div>`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling You are correct! When looking at the style sheet it looks like it Chrome is actually reading an older version of my .css document which does not contain my h1 styles or my .timeline class (it even includes lines that I have previously deleted). I'm really not sure why it would be reading an older file.

Comment: @TunjiOyeniran I am not using Bootstrap, but I am using a boiler plate called Skeleton which inlcudes a grid system hence the class of "row".

Comment: @Ninoid Sounds like your cache is the problem. Ideally, verify by going to another PC that has never pulled the file before, and hit the content. If you get the latest version, your browser cache is the culprit. If the other machine gets the old content, the server perhaps truly has an older file that it is serving up.

Comment: It seems like it is something to do with that. I've switched over to MAMP server and it seems to be working for now. If the problem persists I will look at possibly troubleshooting from another PC. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing breaks.
After replicating your code on my xampp and testing it as both `.html` and `.php`
They both have the same result.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
      h1 {
        font-weight: 650;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .timeline {
        width: 10px;
        height: 2000px;
        background: #454545;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 46px;">
      <h1> BIOGRAPHY </h1>

      Is this working!?

      <div class="timeline"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**if you still have an issue, I would suggest you**

1. Restart your Xampp Server
2. Tryout another browser

**+++ GOODLUCK +++**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to run the code. It seems like my issue, as you mentioned was to do with the server or the browser. I tried as you suggested to restart the xampp server which didn't seem to make a difference and Adobe bracket's live preview didn't like it when I attempted to change live preview browser from Chrome to something else. I switched over to MAMP server and it seems to be working for me on Chrome. If it does end up breaking again I will definitely try another browser to preview my site. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update and a solution that I have found. I ended up switching to another local server and eventually ran into the same issue.

So the issue was actually down to the browser Cache..

The simple solution was to do a hard refresh on Chrome **(CTRL + F5)**. This forced Chrome to read my up to date CSS file from the server.

I hope this helps someone with the same issue. And thanks for everyone's help in pointing me to all of the possible issues.

I am glad I will be able to continue to use Bracket's useful live preview feature! :)

Comment: Oh, so it was a caching problem. Hm Browsers, they always help us too much.